Why "Each constant expression shall evaluate to..." instead of "Each evaluated constant expression shall evaluate to..."?
n3301, 6.6 Constant expressions, p4 (emphasis added):

Each constant expression shall evaluate to a constant that is in the range of representable values for
its type.

n3301, 6.5.15 Logical OR operator, p4 (emphasis added):

If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated.

Question: why the 1st requirement does not depend on the requirement of evaluation (or non-evaluation) of such constant expression?
In other words: why "Each constant expression shall evaluate to..." instead of "Each evaluated constant expression shall evaluate to..."?
Is this an oversight?

Reason of the question: some people believe that "Each constant expression shall evaluate to..." takes precedence (i.e. stronger, has more priority) over the "second operand is not evaluated".
Yes, the n3301 has footnote 119:


Thus, in the following initialization,

static int i = 2 || 1 / 0;

the expression is a valid integer constant expression with value one.

However, "In ISO standards, notes are without exception non-normative."

6.5.15 < 6.6 ... so logical or takes precedence over constant expression. Just kidding :)

Why do you think 2 || 1 / 0 isn't a constant-expression? It does "evaluate to a constant that is in the range of representable values for its type. Put in other words, can you give an example of a constant-expression that isn't evaluated?

@ikegami isn't an operand an expression itself? That rule would apply to each of the involved expressions then. And 1/0 would never be evaluated.

@Gerhard, Yes, it would be a valid expression. But so what? The fact that 1 / 0 isn't a valid constant-expression (e.g. one couldn't use case 1 / 0) doesn't mean that it can't be part of one.

The quote at issue is part of the definition of constant-expression, the grammar rule is used in places where code is expected to be evaluated at compile-time. This means that constant-expression are usually evaluated unconditionally (at compile-time). Introducing the concept of a constant-expression that isn't evaluated is unhelpful and unnecessary.

2 || 1 / 0 is a valid constant-expression because it's a valid conditional-expression that meets the constraints of constant-expression.
Relevantly, it evaluates to 1, so it does "evaluate to a constant that is in the range of representable values for its type."
Evaluating 2 || 1 / 0 doesn't evaluate 1 / 0, but that doesn't mean that 2 || 1 / 0 can't be evaluated.
Therefore, 2 || 1 / 0 can be used where a constant-expression is expected. For example, case 2 || 1 / 0 is valid (although quite odd).
Demo on Compiler Explorer.

While 1 / 0 is a valid conditional-expression, it doesn't meet the constraints of constant-expression, so it's not a valid constant-expression.
Specifically, it doesn't "evaluate to a constant that is in the range of representable values for its type."
Therefore, 1 / 0 can't be used where a constant-expression is expected. For example, case 1 / 0 is invalid.
Demo on Compiler Explorer.

Thanks. I confused "constant expression" with "constant subexpression".

Extra questions: 1) Does it mean that C standard doesn't require that each constant subexpression shall evaluate to a constant that is in the range of representable values for its type? 2) The precedence of / operator is higher than the precedence of || operator. Does it mean that when evaluating 2 || 1 / 0 a C compiler may first evaluate 1 / 0 to, say, <invalid> and second evaluate 2 || <invalid> to 2? 3) In what order a typical C compiler (e.g. GCC, Clang, MSVC, ICC) evaluates 2 || 1 / 0?


There is no rule called "subexpression" or "constant subexpression". 2) No, because of the short-circuiting nature of ||. The RHS is only evaluated if the LHS is true. You quoted the relevant rule in your question. 3) It must not evaluate the RHS of the ||. So it must produce code that generates 1.


Have a look at DR#31: "the Committee's judgement of the intent is that the ``representable'' requirement applies to each subexpression of a constant expression". Since "Each constant expression shall evaluate to..." requirement does not distinguish between evaluated and non-evaluated constant expression, the "representable" requirement shall apply to each subexpression (e.g. 1 / 0). Any comments?

Interesting, but moot. Evaluating INT_MAX + 2 results in an overflow. The same goes for (INT_MAX*4)/4. But evaluating 2 || 1 / 0 doesn't. So unlike the examples in the linked document, at no part during the evaluation of 2 || 1 / 0 do you get a value that's not representable.

gcc adopts this view as well. Note that while gcc doesn't issue any diagnostics for 2 || 1 / 0 as a constant-expression, it does for INT_MAX + 2 and for (INT_MAX*4)/4. Not just an overflow warning, but also an additional warning that it's a constant expression being overflowed and thus a violation of DR#31.

Part of the question is what is the constant expression in the (non-normative) note:
static int i = 2 || 1 / 0; 

If it's the whole expression i = 2 || 1 / 0 then it can be evaluated because the left-to-right shortcut rule (that in a || b if a is true then b is not evaluated) means the constant expression does evaluate to a constant in the representable range.
That is notwithstanding that the sub-expression 1 / 0 cannot be evaluated (at all) let alone to a constant that can be represented...
I do see the OP's point. I think I'm inferring that the constant expression is the whole right-hand side of the assignment. It's the useful interpretation.
I don't think the specification quite nails what a constant expression is. Something around 'A constant expression is an expression that could be evaluated during translation' would help and that is different from 'A constant expression can be evaluated during translation'. I'm reading 'can' as different from is, must or even should.
The specification goes on to specify things that are constant expressions and even allows for implementation dependent extensions.
It also says 'The semantic rules for the evaluation of a constant expression are the same as for nonconstant
expressions.' and provides the (non-normative) note regarding the example given above.
But pedantically that still (at least in principle) doesn't contradict that the (sub-) expression 1/0 qualifying as a constant expression.
It's definitely a language-lawyer question because I think people familiar with C know the intention of the authors the question is whether they have quite unambiguously and precisely nailed it.
